# I am getting error while ndk build in android.mk file

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, android.mk

I am getting error during ndk build. I have only one android.mk file and only one Application.mk file in my project
**Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'protobuf' in /home/parag.j/AndroidArm//jni/Android.mk.

Android NDK: But this module was already defined by /home/parag.j/AndroidArm//jni/Android.mk.**

Here is my Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE=ndktest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES=ndktest.cpp
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := c++_shared
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/inc/build/libc++_shared.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := armnn
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/inc/build/libarmnn.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := armnnTfParser
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/inc/build/libarmnnTfParser.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := protobuf
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/inc/build/libprotobuf.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lm -llog -landroid
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DARM_NEON_64BIT -O3 -mfpu=neon -mcpu=kryo -std=c++14 -pie
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := opencv_java3 armnn armnnTfParser protobuf c++_shared
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES  :=   $(LOCAL_PATH)/inc/include\
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Here is my Application.mk file

```
APP_ABI:=arm64-v8a 
APP_CFLAGS += -Ofast
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_PLATFORM := android-22
ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME := clang++
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to (re)set `LOCAL_MODULE` for the last  part of your makefile. I think the last few lines should be:

```
LOCAL_MODULE=ndktest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES=ndktest.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lm -llog -landroid
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DARM_NEON_64BIT -O3 -mfpu=neon -mcpu=kryo -std=c++14 -pie
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := opencv_java3 armnn armnnTfParser protobuf c++_shared
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES  :=   $(LOCAL_PATH)/inc/include
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

(and get rid of the ndktest lines at the start of the file, of course)

Comment: it working fine but  i am getting "Circular /home/parag.j/AndroidArm//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libprotobuf.so <- /home/parag.j/AndroidArm//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libprotobuf.so dependency dropped." for one .so file